# How would I create an iterator that reverses the given string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a "Reverse Iterator" in Java, which takes a string and outputs each string in reverse order. This is my code now:

```
//a b c d -> d c b a
class ReverseIterator implements Iterator<String> {
  String given;
  int index;
  ReverseIterator(String given) {
    this.given = given;
    this.index = 0;
  }

  // is there a next?
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.index <= this.given.length();
  }

  // gets the next item
  // effect: advances the index by one
  public String next() {
    String answer = this.given.substring(given.length() - this.index, given.length() - this.index - 1);
    this.index = index + 1;
    return answer;
  }
}
```

I'm getting a `String index out of range: -1`, but I'm not sure how to fix my algorithm so it works.

Comment: <= length is always wrong when you're zero-indexed. I'd look at that, first.

Comment: You should not start at index 0, I guess. Rather start (in the constructor) with `this.index = given.length()`. Now you can *decrement* the index until you reach 0. That would reverse the string quite nicely.

Comment: why not having an index = length -1 and keep moving backwards until you reach 0 ? You can use string.charAt(index) to get the char.

Comment: Your `from` (`5`) index is greater then your `to` (`4`) index, the indices should be from smallest to largest

Comment: Instead of creating a substring of 1 character, you should consider using String.charAt(index) method. It would make the debugging much easier

Comment: Thanks everyone! I swapped the arguments in .substring and it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things are wrong.

First `return this.index <= this.given.length();` is going to produce an error when you reach the last character, as `String` is zero indexed, ie `0` to `length - 1`

Second

```
this.given.substring(given.length() - this.index, given.length() - this.index - 1);
```

Produces an index range where the `endIndex` is less then the `beginIndex` (hence the error `String index out of range: -1`)

So, if `index` is 5, you're trying to get the substring starting at `5` and end at `4`, which is invalid.  You want switch those around, something more like...

```
public String next() {
    int from = given.length() - this.index - 1;
    int to = given.length() - this.index;
    String answer = this.given.substring(from, to);
    this.index = index + 1;
    return answer;
}
```

Most of this was debugged with a series of `System.out.println` statements, it's really important that when you start hitting issues like this, that you take the time to break you variables out (like I did above) and inspect there actual values, it's really helpful for highlighting the silly mistakes we all make

Oh, also, I agree `String#charAt` would seem to make more sense

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a beginner programming student at college so I'm still very new to this, but I learned a lot from your post.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments in the substring method are mixed up which is causing the exception:

For a given string of length 5, you want to access the substring from index 5 to 4 which is not possible.

If you change the arguments your next() method will return the last char as a string.

now you have to add the hasNext() method and a loop to your code and you should be good to go.